# Recursive, multi-connection FTP program to use in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ftp

I want to download a big quantity of files from other host directly in my VPS via SSH.
Reason: The VPS bandwidth is so much faster than my home connection, and I won't download files from the host to my PC and then upload to the VPS.

I've already used **wget**, which has directory recursion but uses only one connection, making the process slow.

I've also tested **aria2** which has multiple connection, but no directory recursion.

Comment: Are you downloading all files from the same 'other server'? Does the speed increase when you start wget twice?  (I am asking because you might not gain any speed if you are already filling the bandwidth 'pipe' of one of the two servers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SSH is setup already, the simplest is probably using `scp`. `scp -r ~/localfolder/ username@remote-host.com:/remote/path/to/files/` will do the job, and copy all directories recursively, as you would expect `cp -r` to do.

Comment: I used and it significantly increased the download speed. Thanks!